# Can CSS be inherited from adjacent elements?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

So, I'm doing this:

```css
.ui-table-wrapper-top {
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
}
.ui-table-wrapper-bottom {
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
}
/* pass this to the table ... */
.ui-table-wrapper-top ~ table,
.ui-table-wrapper-bottom ~ table {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

telling a table that has a wrapper that it would get a border.

**Question**:
If some other element set this:

```css
.ui-page-theme-foo .ui-table-wrapper-top,
.ui-page-theme-foo .ui-table-wrapper-bottom {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Is there a way to inherit this color to the `table`, because it should only get a border color, if it has a wrapper (top/bottom)?

Comment: I don't see what the difference is between your two situations... I mean, why can't you just do the `~ table` thingy again?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. You cannot affect the way property inheritance works through CSS (i.e. make an element inherit from anywhere but its parent); you can only override it by making an element inherit when it would normally not have and the reverse.